# -2147221231, 'ClassFactory cannot supply requested class', None, None

Tags: python-2.7

I am using the following code to reclassify multiple raster at once using python.  after the "GP = win32com.client.Dispatch("esriGeoprocessing.GPDispatch.1")" line I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    GP = win32com.client.Dispatch("esriGeoprocessing.GPDispatch.1")
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 108, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 85, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
com_error: (-2147221231, 'ClassFactory cannot supply requested class', None, None)
```

Does anyone know what the problem can be? ALso under reclassTable I am not using a .dbf but a .csv excel file.  Could that be the reason?  I don't know how to make a .dbf file.
Thanks ahead for any much needed help/
Kristin

## code

```
inputDir = "c:\\tmp\\gis\\rasterReclass\\"                         # where all the rasters are located

outputDir = "c:\\tmp\\gis\\rasterReclass\\"                        # where the output rasters are to be saved

outputPrefix = "R_"                                                # prefix of the output rasters

reclassTable = r"c:\tmp\gis\rasterReclass\reclassTable.dbf"        # the reclass data table

fieldRasterName = "RASTERNAME"                                     # column with the name of the raster

fieldRasterThreshold = "THRESHOLD"                                 # column with the threshold value


import win32com.client, sys

GP = win32com.client.Dispatch("esriGeoprocessing.GPDispatch.1")

GP.RefreshCatalog(inputDir)

GP.RefreshCatalog(outputDir)

total = 0

ok = 0

tableRows = GP.SearchCursor(reclassTable)

tableRow = tableRows.Next()

while tableRow:
    
print ""
    
total = total + 1
    
rasterName = tableRow.GetValue(fieldRasterName)
   
 threshold = tableRow.GetValue(fieldRasterThreshold)
    
sourceRaster = inputDir + rasterName
    
print "Processing " + rasterName + " with threshold value " + str(threshold)
    
if GP.Exists(sourceRaster):
       
 expression = "SetNull(\"" + sourceRaster + "\" < " + str(threshold) + ", 1)"

        
outputRaster = outputDir + outputPrefix + rasterName
        
try:
            
GP.SingleOutputMapAlgebra(expression, outputRaster)
            
print "... done"
            
ok = ok + 1
        
except:
           
 print "... " + rasterName + " failed"
    
    
else:
        
print rasterName + " does not exists"

    
    tableRow = tableRows.Next()


print "--------------------------"

print str(ok) + " out of " + str(total) + " rasters sucessfully reclassified !"
```

Comment: This problem doesn't appear to be with the Python code but rather with some installation/configuration issue with the ESRI COM object.  Tentatively, try re-installing and re-registering this component.

Comment: Hi MJV,Thanks for the comment.  Do you mean to reinstall ArcGIS?  I am not 100% on what the ESRI com object is and how to re-install that component.

Comment: Yes, user2379814, this is `ArcGIS`.  "ESRI" is just the name of the company (I think originally "Environmental System Research Institute") .  ArcGIS is their flagship product.  I'm unsure that reinstalling this software will fix the issue, but the symptoms are akin to some DLL versioning issues.